# Send SQL Commands to SQLPlus via Process in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, process, sqlplus

since apparently my other idea how to send multiple Statements to the Oracle DB was not so easy I have to do it differently...

I want to use SQLPlus over Process to issue all possible Oracle SQL Commands.
I now have the problem that the Statements are never added to the Shell. Ie.: When this Code is run it will open the Shell and say "connected to: Oracle ...." and then show the "SQL>" prompt.

The result will be: **"SP2-0042 Unknown command "test"**, which is okay. However when it wants to run the SQL query it only writes into the Shell **"SQL> 2"** and nothing happens. The DB is not changed either. If I add another Query it will write "3" into the same Line.

```
      ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        processInfo.Arguments = "user/password@db";
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
        processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

        // Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processInfo;

        //process.OutputDataReceived += (sender,args) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ohh i got something"); };
        //process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ohh i got some error"); };

        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(" test");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);


        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("create or replace view test(ID) as select ID from USER");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
      process.StandardInput.Flush();
 
       // process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

I don´t see what is missing, I am doing everything like in all those Examples online.
Btw, can I somehow get if an Command has already been executed or will I have to parse the DataReceived Event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQL> 2` you are seeing is because you are writing to the [the SQL buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-73BED34F-03FF-4C61-9813-8B2E387EE82B), but you are not then executing that buffer. You would see the same thing if you manually typed that statement into the SQL*Plus client and hit return.

You need to [end the SQL command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-33A1B51B-2DF4-41CE-9656-D35400201208).

You can do that to either change your statement to end with a semicolon:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("create or replace view test(ID) as select ID from USER;");
```

or send a slash as a separate line:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("create or replace view test(ID) as select ID from USER");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("/");
```

Incidentally, `USER` is a built-in function and reserved word, so you can't have a table called that unless it's a quoted identifier - which it's usually better to avoid using.

Once it's working you might want to look at some of the `set` commands to modify the responses you see - you probably don't want to see the command echoed back to you for example, and might not want to see all feedback. You may also want to add the `-s` argument to hide the SQL*Plus banner etc.

(Also note that adding a semicolon is the opposite of advice that's often seen to avoid ORA-00933 or ORA-00911 errors; but that's because of how you are running this. SQL*Plus treats a semicolon as a statement separator and terminator and it causes execution to occur, but it is not part of the SQL buffer. With JDBC or a native .Net ODP DB call you can only execute one statement at a time and the semicolon is then irrelevant and illegal. With a direct call your current statement, without a semicolon, would be OK. Via SQL*Plus it is not...)